# Is it bad design to pass the containing object as an argument to a method of a contained object?

Tags: c#, oop, containment

Is it bad design to pass the containing object as an argument to a method of a contained object, like in the simplified example below?

```
class A
{
    private B _containedObject;

    public A(B b)
    {
            _containedObject = b;
            //...
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
            //...
            _containedObject.SomeMethod(this);
            //...
    }
}

class B
{
    public void SomeMethod(A a)
    {
            //do something with a
    }
}
```

P.s. The above example is simplified to illustrate merely the containment relation and passing the containing object to the contained object, and does not in itself illustrate the purpose of doing so. Rest assured though that there is a purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are times when you might want to pass the containing object as a parameter to a contained object. As other posters have noted, it is called "double dispatch". The Smalltalk language provides a classic example.

The example is about adding together integers and floats (or other types of numbers). In C++ or Java, your integer class would have polymorphic methods like:

```
Integer {
     add(Float) {...}
     add(Integer) {...}
     add(UserDefinedType) {...}
}
```

Each add method could implement the different kinds of addition correct. The compiler uses the type information to select the right method. The statement Integer(6).add(Float(1.0)) would invoke the Integer::add(Float) method.

Smalltalk, unlike C++ and Java, is dynamically typed. A Smalltalk class can only have one method named **add**.

Integer::add(Object)

The compiler does not know the class of "object". For that reason, Smalltalk cannot implement the **add** the same way as C++ or Java. Instead, Smalltalk uses double dispatch. It works like this:

```
   Integer {
          add(Object o) {
              return o.addToInteger(this)
          }        
    }
```

The other number classes like Float, Fraction and even Integer implement the method addToInteger().

```
Float {
      addToInteger(Object o) {
          //Perform float + in math
          return result
     }
}
```

Double dispatch solves the problem of how to implement man operations polymorphically in a dynamically typed language. But there is a more common use: the visitor pattern. I'll put that in a separate answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have accepted this answer because this (together with your other answer about visitor pattern) provides the most complete and useful information.

Answer (score 2):

in this simple example it looks like a form of double dispatch. in which case I would pass A as a method argument of B.

```
void SomeMethod(A a)
{
    a.DoSomething(this);
}
```

however, this is just one example. there are other times where passing in the object as a ctor argument may be more beneficial.

Comment: I fail to see the point of your answer. Passing A as an argument to B.SomeMethod is what I am already doing. And from there passing B (this) back to A is not necessary (at least not in my case). Please explain further.

Comment: your sample code was vague with no real problem explained. my example adds some definition to the sample code. the "answer" to your question is "it depends".

Comment: The question was not about the code example, but a general question about design that is pretty clear in itself. I only provided the code example to make even more clear what I meant. So what does "it depend" on? (besides the situation potentially being a form of double dispatch, which it does not need to be in all cases)

Comment: it depends on the context. in other words there is no "right" answer. sometimes it makes sense to pass an object as a ctor parameter and sometimes it doesn't. if you're asking about when specifically, then post a specific problem and we can provide a specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not bad design and is used quite often.  You do, however, have to be careful that you don't cause a memory leak if you do this.  When you pass the container object to the inner object, it will hold a reference to the parent until the inner is deleted.

That means if you new up an A, and it news up a b, if you let all other references expire A will still be around because B is holding a copy.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. "When you pass the contained object to the inner object": what is the inner object? or did you mean containING?  Regarding memory leaks: as the code shows, A doesn't construct B objects, it only keeps a reference to B. B doesn't keep any references of A, it only gets A passed in a method call.

Comment: @Peladao - I mean container, not contained.  That's why i said you had to be careful that you don't hold on to a reference, or you provide a Dispose method to allow the object to be released.  No, the example you show is fine, i was just saying that you had to be careful.

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing that out, though I don't find it all that relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the parent of an object exists and is known at the time the object is constructed, and the object will never have any other parent, it's often useful to have each child object keep a reference to the parent when it is constructed.  One will then be able to ask a child object to do something involving its parent without having to pass the parent as an argument, since the child will already know who its parent is.

One wrinkle with this concept is that, depending upon what the classes do, one may want to allow objects of the parent type to limit who can create objects with them as parent.  If the parent and child types will be in the same assembly, this can easily be done with an `internal` modifier on the child's constructor.  If one wishes to allow the possibility that the parent object might be of a class defined in a yet-unwritten assembly, but provide such parent objects the compile-time assurance that they will not be "attached" without their "consent", things are a bit trickier, but could probably be accomplished reasonably well by using a private constructor and a public factory method:

```
public interface IAssuredParent<T>
static childClass createAttachedChild<T,U>(T parent) where T:IAssuredParent<U>
{...};
```

If the parent defines `P` private class `XYZ` and implements`IAssuredParent<XYZ>`, it will be the only class with access to type `XYZ`, and thus the only class which can successfully call createAttachedChild with a pair of type parameters that can accommodate an actual parameter of type `P` and comply with the type constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the most common reason for using this technique is the visitor pattern. I'm having a terrible time finding an example I like on the Web, so I'll just use class diagram from the Wikipedia article. Have a look at this diagram: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/VisitorPatternUML.png

Now image a car part accepting a visitor object:

```
Engine myEngine;
CarElementPrintVistor myVisitor;
myEngine.accept(myVisitor);
```

But inside the accept() method, the car part turns right around and passes itself to the visitor!

```
myVisitor.visit(this)
```

Check out the Visitor design pattern for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view this is not a so good design in order to improve it you could declare an interface of your object A and declare your SomeMethod after like:

```
void SomeMethod(IMyInterface a)
```

then your A class will looks like:

```
public class A : IMyInterface
{
  ....
}
```

So this method will give an abstraction in implementation.

In general better design == less relations.

Comment: this is generally a good practice, but i think it's missing the point of the question. It's not about what reference is passed in, but how it's passed.

Comment: @AlexTheo Totally true. I'm doing this in the real code, but good that you mention it.

Comment: @AlexTheo - Interface based design is a good practice, but irrelevant to the question.  The question was whether or not passing a referernce to a container (interface based or not) is a good idea.